# Differences between various permission levels in Django

Tags: django, permissions, system, authentication

As far as I know, there are 3 permission levels available to use in django (whether by django itself or by using 3rd party apps).
1) Model-based permission
2) Object based permission
3) Row-based permission

It would be great if you tell me the exact differences between these 3 levels of permission system.

Comment: Please let me know about the source that hints of the permission levels.

Comment: There are many sources on the net. This is a good example:
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you got that info, but it's not even remotely correct. Django technically doesn't have *any* permission system. The `auth` contrib app adds a system of "permissions" but it's optional and could be replaced entirely with something else. The `admin` app (also a contrib package, and optional) uses `auth`, so if you're talking about the Django admin, or using the `auth` package with your own app(s), then we can talk.

In `auth`, you have `User`s, `Group`s and `Permission`s. `User`s come in either "superuser" or "regular" user flavors, and every model in your project gets three `Permission`s automatically when you run syncdb (with `auth` included in `INSTALLED_APPS`): can_add, can_change, and can_delete. `User`s marked as "superusers" (`is_superuser == True`), can take any action on any model. Other users need to have `Permission`s explicitly assigned to them. Further, `Group`s may have `Permission`s assigned to them, and then, any `User` assigned to that `Group` inherits those permissions.

So, a user could have no ability to do anything with any model, some combination of add, change or delete capability with some or all models or complete access to do anything with any model. There's no concept of "object-based" permissions, in the sense of an "instance". You can either either edit every instance of an model or none. There's also no concept of "row-based" permission. A row in the database table is merely an instance of the model, anyways.

Comment: But according to the following link, we have Object-based permission. "Django-Authority" and "Django-Guardian" are some examples of the apps available to provide permission levels other than Model-based level.
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/

Comment: That's an entirely separate package with no affiliation to Django, other than the fact that it works *with* Django. Like I said, the `auth` package could be completely substituted with something else or merely supplemented with something else. But, at that point, we're not talking about Django any more.

Comment: Yep! I am aware of this. That's why I mentioned 3rd party apps in my original post.
Now, I really need to know the differences between these permission levels. Which package is the most popular and stable at this time?

Comment: Oh, so in other words, this question should be closed because "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: Oh! I didn't mean to raise any debate or argument question. I was only trying to find out the difference between 'Row' and 'Object' based permission levels.

Comment: I explained the difference in my answer: there is none. "Object" is in terms of how Python views it. "Row" is in terms of how the database views it. But they're basically the same thing in this situation.